# prove that $\ln (x^2+ cos^2x)$ is uniformly continuous.

Tags: calculus

I know that the direction of the proof is to show that the derivative of the function is bounded, and hence meets the Lipschitz condition. So I differentiated it:

$$f'(x) = \frac{2x-\sin2x}{x^2 + \cos^2x}$$

But I am stuck here. I can't manage to show that it is bounded.

EDIT: 
The domain is $\Bbb R$

Comment: Here's what you can do: Show that the denominator is never zero. Asymptotically, the function behaves as $\frac{1}{x}$ so as long as there are no singularities (i.e. the denominator is never zero), the derivative will be bounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show that the limits as $|x| \to \infty$ are both $0$. So there is some interval $[-a, a]$ where $f'(x)< 1$ for $x \not \in [-a,a]$. Then show that $f'(x)$ is continuous on $[-a,a]$, and therefore takes a maximum.